# webpack ReactJS: Unexpected token at this.setState

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, foreach, webpack

I am trying to change state of all the elements in an array in ReactJS as shown below. This is my First application, so I am not able to know what is wrong in over here.

```
closeState(){
    this.state.itemList.forEach(function(itemInd){
        this.setState({ itemInd.expState : 0 });
    }
});
```

It gives me `Unexpected token` error

I have

```
     this.state = {
         ...........
        itemList: [],
         .....
     }
```

each element in itemList has : `title, desc, expState`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you chose wrong way to solve this issue., from your example I understood that you want to set `expState` to `0`, for each element in `itemList`., if it is true better do it like this

```
const newItemListState = this.state.itemList.map((itemInd) => {
  return Object.assign(itemInd, { expState: 0 });
});

this.setState({ itemList: newItemListState })
```

---

In your example you have several mistakes

1. You forgot add `)` after callback function
2. You need set `this` for `.forEach` callback, or use `arrow function`

   2.1. `this.state.itemList.forEach(function(itemInd) { }, this);`

   2.2. `this.state.itemList.forEach((itemInd) => { });`
3. You can't use this `{ itemInd.expState : 0 }` expression.